How to use pxcptinfoptrs in mingw64 so as to recover the Exception Pointers?
I found this function in signal.h in mingw w64 (Windows 64bit 10 pro, x64 compiler)

extern void **__cdecl __pxcptinfoptrs(void);

Can use it in a signal handler to get the ExceptionRecord?
My working code with g++ -fnon-call-exceptions is this one
// This sample demonstrates how try {} block disables handler set by signal()
// on MinGW-w64 with GCC SJLJ build
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>

static void SIGWntHandler (int signum)//sub_code)
{
  std::cout << "In signal handler, signum = " << signum << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Now exiting..." << std::endl;
  //std::exit(1);
  
  throw("OK");
}


void do_something_bad(void) {
      char* ptrnull = 0;
      ptrnull[0] = '\0'; // cause access violation
}

int main (void)
{
  std::cout << "Entered main(), arming signal handler..." << std::endl;
  if (signal (SIGSEGV, (void(*)(int))SIGWntHandler) == SIG_ERR)
    std::cout << "Failed setting signal handler\n";

  // this try block disables signal handler...
  try { std::cout << "In try block" << std::endl; } catch(char*) {}

  std::cout << "Doing bad things to cause signal..." << std::endl;
  
  try {
    do_something_bad();
  } catch(char const* cvc) {std::cout << cvc << std::endl;}

  std::cout << "We are too lucky..." << std::endl;
  
  if (signal (SIGILL, SIG_DFL)  == SIG_ERR)
    std::cout << "Failed restoring signal handler\n";
  return 0;
}


Try EXCEPTION_POINTERS **ep = (EXCEPTION_POINTERS**)__pxcptinfoptrs();.

@ssbssa it did not work. Do you have a working sample?
